# How to build a Docker image for an app with local dependencies in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, docker, dockerfile, nestjs, monorepo

I have a monorepo with the following structure:

```
root/
├── node_modules
├── tsconfig.references.json
├── package.json
├── apps/
│   ├── api/
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── dist/
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   └── Dockerfile
└── packages/
    ├── types/
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── dist/
    │   └── src/
    └── config/
        ├── package.json
        ├── tsconfig.json
        ├── dist/
        ├── src/
        └── tsconfig/
            └── tsconfig.base.json
```

Where the `apps/api` package depends on the `packages/types` and `packages/config` packages.

I am building the Docker image with the following Dockerfile like so:

#### Dockerfile

```yaml
# Define a base image
FROM node:16-slim as build-stage

# Install TypeScript
RUN npm install -g typescript@4.7.4

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files
COPY . .
RUN npm install

# Build config package
WORKDIR /app/packages/config
#RUN npm link  <- tried to npm link too but no luck 
RUN npm run build


# Build types package
WORKDIR /app/packages/types
#RUN npm link
RUN npm run build


# Build api app
WORKDIR /app/apps/api
# RUN npm link @myapp/types <- tried to npm link too but no luck 
# RUN npm link @myapp/config
RUN npm run build

# Define a new stage for production
FROM node:16-slim as production-stage

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the necessary files and directories
COPY --from=build-stage /app/apps/api/package*.json ./apps/api/
COPY --from=build-stage /app/apps/api/dist ./apps/api/dist

COPY --from=build-stage /app/packages/types/dist ./packages/types/dist
COPY --from=build-stage /app/packages/types/package.json ./packages/types/package.json

COPY --from=build-stage /app/packages/config/dist ./packages/config/dist
COPY --from=build-stage /app/packages/config/package.json ./packages/config/package.json


# Install production dependencies only
WORKDIR /app/apps/api
RUN npm install --only=production

# Set the command to run
CMD ["node", "dist/src/main"]
```

The build works fine but upon running the container I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find module '@myapp/types'

If I try try to build and run the image with only the `build-stage` everything works.

So my guess is that the issue is likely linked to the absence of `node_modules` folder at the root of the app in the `production-stage` as this folder would hold references to the symlinks the `file:....` in the package.json from the `api` package are pointing to.

That said, since the types are a devDependency I would expect them to be compiled as part of my `api/dist` folder and the links already resolved...?

But copying the root node_modules as part of the `production-stage` seems to be an awful idea.

So I am not clear on how to take this forward.

What would the best way to approach this?

Thanks,